# Is the hector_gazebo_plugins plugin built-in or do I build it myself?

Tags: ros, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm pretty new to Gazebo, so I apologize.  I'm confused about Gazebo plugins.  I have used the skid steer plugin and the differential drive plugins that were in a Gazebo tutorial and they both worked fine in my robot models.  So I know how to use plugins, at least a little.

Now I'm starting to add sensors to my robot models and I can't figure out how to use the hector_gazebo_plugins GazeboRosSonar plugin.
http://wiki.ros.org/hector_gazebo_plugins

Is this something that is already built into Gazebo or ROS or is this something that I need to download and build on my machine?  If the latter, then where are the download and install instructions?  The above URL appears to just be API documentation.

I'm using ROS Hydro and Gazebo 1.9.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6541/is-the-hector_gazebo_plugins-plugin-built-in-or-do-i-build-it-myself?/) by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/879/kurt-leucht/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 50 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You may as well install the compiled one with:

`$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-hector-gazebo-plugins`

What are you using for your robot model?  `.urdf` or `.sdf`? Assuming `.urdf` [here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_models/blob/hydro-devel/hector_sensors_description/urdf/sonar_sensor.urdf.xacro#L33) you can find an usage example.

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Francisco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/314/francisco/) with karma: 143 on 2014-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/879/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-07-05**:
Thanks.  I'm new enough that I sometimes forget to try the ros-[version]-[package name] naming convention.

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/879/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-07-07**:
It works!  Thanks!

**Comment by [BlackViper](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6212/blackviper/) on 2018-08-09**:
I know this is a two year old question, but I am in the same boat. How did you make it work? I tried replacing the {name} with my link name and setting the visualization to true but there is no laser visualization in gazebo.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You need to download these plugins. You can do this from this page :

https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo

You have to download/clone this into your catkin workspace and run `catkin_make.`
then you can use the hector_gazebo plugins.

---

Originally posted by [Bharath](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/878/bharath/) with karma: 21 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1